# Modify policy function at runtime in sails.js

Tags: javascript, express, sails.js

Is it possible to modify a policy function when sails.js is running? Something like:

```
sails.middleware.policies.isauthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  req.user = { id: 1 };
  next();
};
```

What I intended is to replace the isAuthenticated policy when testing a route (e.g. /GET books) for a specific user.

Comment: Do you want to disable access to some books depending on the user id ?

Comment: Question not clear.